# Phone stopped showing up on the list of remote devices for Chrome Developer Tools; revoking the USB authorization had no effect

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging, google-chrome-console

My phone stopped showing up on the list of remote devices (it used to work fine for debugging, but now, for some reason, does not).  I tried revoking the USB debugging authorization, unplugging and re-plugging in my phone, closing chrome and reopening it, and restarting my phone, all to no success.  My phone shows up in the list of connected USB devices on my computer and I can browse the directories on the phone, so it's not a connection issue.  The phone is a Samsung Galaxy 7, running Android 7.0, the latest version available from Samsung and I am using Canary/the developer version of Chrome (but I have also tried using the release version to the same effect). 
Anyone have any other ideas of what the problem could be?
Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that you don't have adb running (or Android Studio)

Comment: Nope, still not showing up... ;-\